# Loop to add groups and layers based on user's checkbox choice

Tags: leaflet, javascript, wms

I have a number of layers that I would like the user to choose from a checkbox to feed the map.

All these layers are based in a WMS call, controlled by a user input string. All working properly

The problem is when I try to get the user input checkboxes to dinamically generate layergroups or featuregroups, each containing a layer that is returned from a WMS call. When I do it manually, it works fine. But when I try to loop and add each layer to a different group, it doesn't work.

Here is what I've been trying:

```
$('#exec').on('click', function () {
            var r_layers = [];
            var currentLayer = [];
            var selected = [];
            $('#checks input:checked').each(function () {
                selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
                r_layers = [
                    L.tileLayer.wms(connString, {
                        layers: 'IR:r_'+selected[i]+'_'+f_value+'_'+'a'+as_value,
                        transparent: true,
                        format: 'image/png',
                        username: 'xxx',
                        password: 'xxx'
                    })                        
                ]
                //currentLayer = r_layers[i];
                var groupLayers = new L.featureGroup();
                groupLayers.addTo(map);
                r_layers[i].addTo(groupLayers);
                ctrlLayers.addOverlay(groupLayers, 'Layer' + i)

            }
        }
```

It only adds one layer, not sure why. I've tried to alert() the values to make sure the loop is running complete, also alert() the string to make sure it's changing on each, but it's still not working.

Comment: Code logic does not make much sense, but since at each iteration you create new `r_layers[0]` layer, it should be `r_layers[0].addTo(groupLayers);`. Other possibility would be to have `r_layers[i] = L.tileLayer.wms(...`, then you can keep `r_layers[i].addTo(groupLayers);`

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks for the answer. I think I was missing push() in order to store the values into the array. After that it started working. But why exactly do you think the logic doesn't make sense? What I want is the user to be able to choose what layers he want to load into the map before making wms request.

Comment: There are several reasons code logic doesn't make sense: (1) Each time you click checkbox to add new overlay, all the existing overlays are added again. (2) If you click select checkbox to remove the overlay, it's not removed, just already selected overlays are added again (3) Your are adding tile (raster) layer to feature group, which is intended for vector layers (4) There is no sense in having group layers with a single member layer. Layer can be added to the map directly. (4) There is no sense in having `r_layers` as array, if you only use the first element again and again.

Comment: I understand but since I have about 80 layers to add into the map, I honestly don't know the best approach to do so. It's either that or adding the layers manually in the code, which would be a lot of effort to maintain. About the existing layers in the layer group I would clear all before start adding so it won't duplicate. Do you think there is a different approach for adding these layers dinamically without having this kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To efficiently add/remove layers to/from them map with checkbox selection, you need some inventory of the layers that have been already created. For this purpose you can have some object `layers`, where created layers are stored, each layer under it's own unique property, where property name can be checkbox value.

Logic of adding/removing layers can then go something like this:

- At each `#exec` click loop through all the checkboxes (not just selected).
- For each checkbox check if layer already exists.
- If layer exists, check if layer is displayed on map.
- If layer is displayed and checkbox is not checked, remove layer from the map.
- If layer is not displayed and checkbox is checked, add layer to the map.
- If layer does not exist and checkbox is checked, create layer and add it to the map.

Code could then look something like this (not tested):

```
var layers = {};

$('#exec').on('click', function () {
  var wmsLayerName, layer, isChecked, checkboxValue;
  $('#checks input').each(function () {
    checkboxValue = $(this).attr('value');
    isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    wmsLayerName = 'IR:r_' + checkboxValue + '_' + f_value + '_' + 'a' + as_value;
    layer = layers[checkboxValue];
    if (layer) {
      if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        if (!isChecked) {
          map.removeLayer(layer);
          ctrlLayers.removeLayer(layer);
        }
        }
      else if (isChecked) {
        map.addLayer(layer);
      }
      }
    else if (isChecked) {
      layer = L.tileLayer.wms(connString, {
        layers: wmsLayerName,
        transparent: true,
        format: 'image/png',
        username: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx'
      });
      layers[checkboxValue] = layer;
      map.addLayer(layer);
      ctrlLayers.addOverlay(layer, 'Layer ' + checkboxValue);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: great. that did it. Thanks!